# Use Static List as Cloudformation parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am currently refering to AWS example from here :
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/AutoScalingMultiAZWithNotifications.template

```
"Subnets" : {
      "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
      "Description" : "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
 }
```

And then use

```
{ "Ref" : "Subnets" }
```

Similarly for my use case I am using :

```
"Zone" : {
  "Type" : "List<'land','raw'>",  // Can this be replaced by static List so user can select multiple options 
  "Description" : "The list of landing zone for raw data",
}
```

And then use as

```
{ "Ref" : "Zone" }
```

I am getting errors as unrecognized Type : List<'land','raw'>

Is there a good example to refer for getting the static list as input parameter

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to achieve is not possible. There's not even `"List<String>"` Type, only `CommaDelimitedList`, for which you can't have a select-box with multiple entries to chose from.

Comment: I tried CommaDelimitedList before and as you said , I do not get select-box with multiple entries

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

```
 "Parameters" : {
      "InstanceTypeParameter" : {
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "t2.micro",
        "AllowedValues" : ["t2.micro", "m1.small", "m1.large"],
        "Description" : "Enter t2.micro, m1.small, or m1.large. Default is t2.micro."
      }
    }
```

AllowedValues is static list